# Read only the 5th letter of an html id VB

Tags: vb.net

If the html ids are, lets say "ex_a1", "ex_a2", "ex_a3" ect. Can you use only the 5th letter as a reference?

Like this maybe?

`Dim elements = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")

```
    For Each element As HtmlElement In elements

        If element.GetAttribute("className") = "EXAMPLE" Then
            If 5TH_LETTER_OF_ID = UserChoice then 
            element.InvokeMember("click")
            Exit For
          End If
        End If
    Next`
```

UserChoice is a number between 0 and 16

Comment: How can you only be concerned with the 5th character if the value you are after may be two characters?  If it can be either one or two characters, and there may be other uninteresting characters after it, what rules can you follow to determine where the value ends and the other uninteresting characters begin?

Comment: You can get the 5th character like this: element.Id.ToString().Chars(4)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Contains` method of the `String` class, like this:

```
If element.Id.ToString().Contains(UserChoice) Then
    ' Put logic here if there is a match
End If
```

Comment: But then what if user choice is in the id? the actual id is size_9_23452 with size varying and the last numbers also varying

Comment: Then you need a better naming convention that allows for parsing the value out; depending on looking at the 5th character and then reading one character sometime and then reading two characters another time is destined for failure.